# $\mathbb{P} (X_3=3|X_0=1)$ in a Markov chain

Tags: probability, markov-chains

Given a Markov chain with state $[1,2,3,4]$:

$$
        \begin{matrix}
        \frac{1}{5} &  \frac{2}{5}& \frac{1}{5} & \frac{1}{5}\\
        \frac{3}{4} & \frac{1}{4} & 0 & 0 \\
        \frac{1}{8} & \frac{3}{8} & \frac{3}{8} &\frac{1}{8} \\
        0 & \frac{1}{3} & 0 & \frac{2}{3}\\
        \end{matrix}
$$

I need to find $\mathbb{P}(X_3=3|X_0=1)$.

I tried

$$
 \begin{matrix}  
0.008 & 0.421875 & 0.001953125& 0.00000000\\
 0.064 & 0.015625 & 0.052734375 & 0.03703704\\
0.008 & 0.000000 & 0.052734375 & 0.00000000\\
 0.008 & 0.000000 & 0.001953125 & 0.03703704\\
\end{matrix}
$$

I don't want to compute this manually. I thought of a simpler way:

$1 \rightarrow 1 \rightarrow 1 \rightarrow 3$

$1 \rightarrow 2 \rightarrow 1 \rightarrow 3$

Even then I don't know how to proceed. The answer is $\frac{17}{250}$. Even after cubing my matrix, don't get it. And I would like to know the closed irreducible set and transient set if any?

Comment: It is $P^3_{13}$. I don't think there is a nice trick to make this easier to calculate, because there are quite a few different ways to get from 1 to 3. Also in this case the whole chain is irreducible (1 goes everywhere, 2 goes to 1 which goes everywhere, 3 goes everywhere, 4 goes to 2 which goes to 1 which goes everywhere).

Answer (score 1):

The above comment is correct, I'm just going to offer some additional explanation. To be honest I don't fully understand what you tried to do so far.

Indeed, you could try to calculate this by hand, but then you need to account for **all** possible paths that lead from $1$ to $3$ in 3 steps, and this is going to be tedious.

Instead, notice that if you pre-multiply your matrix $P$ by: $e_1 = \begin{bmatrix}1 & 0& 0& 0 \end{bmatrix}$ you will have the vector of probabilities of each state at $t$, given that at $t-1$ you were at $1$. If you then post-multiply it by you $P$ again, you will obtain vetor of probabilities of each state at $t=2$, and so on. Therefore, the probability of reaching state $3$ after $3$ steps, given that you started at $1$ will be:
$$\mathbb{P}(X_3=3|X_0=1)=e_1\times P \times P \times P \times e^T_3 = e_1 \times P^3 \times e^T_3 = P^3_{13}$$

Comment: The desired answer is actually $e_1 P^3 e_3^T$ (with $e_i$ defined as row vectors like you did). The advantage of this is that you don't need to compute all the irrelevant stuff, you can just multiply $P$ with vectors instead of matrices.

Comment: Yes, of course, thank you. Without post-multiplying by $e^T_3$ you get the whole vector of probabilities for each state at $t=3$.